# jQuery : Mousewheel event for svg

Tags: jquery, svg, mousewheel

I am trying to implement mousewheel event for svg. I am using the below code. This works fine if I use `$(document).bind()` , but it is not working if I use the svg id `svgmain`. I want the mouse wheel to work only inside svg. How to get it?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" > </script>
    <script>
      $("#svgmain").bind("mousewheel", function(event) {
        $("#log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );  
      });
    </script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <svg id="svgmain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="background-color:blue;">
      <g id="g">
        <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following function to bind events to `svg` elements.

```
 $(document).on('mousewheel', "#svgmain", function() {
   // your code here 
  });
```

Working code below.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('mousewheel', "#svgmain", function() {
      $("#log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="log"></div>
  <svg id="svgmain" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="background-color:blue;">
    <g id="g">
      <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```